# Can parent module have a dependencies in his own submodules?

Tags: maven, parent-child, pom.xml, parent-pom

Maven project structure is as follow:

```
moduleA
 -moduleB
 pom.xml
```

- moduleA has a dependency in moduleB. moduleB actually not depend in moduleA.
- Why I don't reverse it? make moduleB parent and moduleA child, because I can't change moduleB pom file. moduleB is a git submodule (I know I can add git repo dependency to moduleA pom file but I was told not to do it).

This structure looks wrong to me even if there is a way to make it work (is there any?).
I thought to add an aggregator pom and change the structure to this:

```
Aggregator 
 -moduleA
 -moduleB
 pom.xml
```

moduleA depends in moduleB.

What do you think?

Comment: First if `moduleA` has a dependency onto `moduleB` than `moduleB` can not be child of `moduleA` because `moduleA` must be of packaging `pom` which does not work. Please make an example project on github or alike...